# Physics is rotting into a bad situation, a request for community manager intervention

Tags: discussion, community

[Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) is experiencing the throes of very bad days. Lots of main and key users (compared to the total number of them) have left or are leaving.

Examples of community destruction, with such users leaving, have been discussed in Physics Meta posts:

- [Have we lost the necessary critical mass of professional physicists?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5102/have-we-lost-the-necessary-critical-mass-of-professional-physicists)
- [I leave Physics SE. This is my good-bye note](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/i-leave-physics-se-this-is-my-good-bye-note)

Others have become inactive:

- [Arnold Neumaier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7924/arnold-neumaier)
- [G. 't Hooft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft) (a Nobel Prize winner)

Many others are suspended:

- [Ron Maimon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon)
- [Dilaton](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2751/dilaton)
- [Dimension10 Abhimanyu PS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23119/dimension10-abhimanyu-ps)

The *professional* aspect of the site is heavily suppressed, and the site is now converting to a homework-answering site.

Now, many of the users there believe that the arguably *authoritarian*, *thoughtless* and *naive* style of moderation is the main cause of these issues.

I didn't ask this using my real account because these type of discussions are considered "useless" and "harmful to the community" there by the moderators. And they're often deleted, such as [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/do-we-agree-with-rons-suspension) , which was exactly a discussion on the same issue.

I want to know if the StackExchange Community Team (those other than the currently involved moderators at Physics Stack Exchange) can intervene and solve the issues.

We really need help.

### Important Note:

- Almost all the mods at Phys.SE are among those knowledgeable academics and experts themselves and their presence is honestly appreciated. Moderation is another story, and what I mean in the question by *bad style of moderation* is mainly caused by some of their decisions, and more importantly those guided by some *external* mods, mostly in the past. (As Shog9 pointed to in his first paragraph of his answer)

Comment: "I didn't use my main account to ask this question" -- Why not?

Comment: Why isn't this posted on meta.physics?  Also, as it is this post contains no useful points to discuss.  What, specifically, is it about the moderation that is causing problems in your eyes.

Comment: Before this gets downvoted to oblivion, can anyone validate what this user is saying? Is there a problem?

Comment: @JoshC I didn't ask at Phys.SE and with my main account, because these kinds of questions are considered *useless* and also *harmful to the community* there, by the moderators, and probably will become deleted, as is this one: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/what-where-is-the-whole-question-do-we-agree-with-insert-here-the-user-who

Comment: Just from the past five minutes of research alone, I've seen that the problem you're describing in this post is significantly contextual and that this really doesn't/can't have enough information for us to accurately address it. A better course would be to use the contact link to email the StackExchange team, who likely have more contextual understanding, and will be more free to respond privately. That, or post on your site-specific meta.

Comment: @slugster Ask a random (active) user at Phys.SE. All users will accept.

Comment: @Emrakul I do not expect you to exactly understand the situation there. I just wanted to know how to contact *someone other than the current moderators at Phys.SE* for help.

Comment: @Vanished If you have serious concerns (which it sounds like you do) about the moderation of and/or culture at Physics.SE, I strongly suggest you write a well-formulated email to the team using their contact link.

Comment: @slugster three high-rep users have been suspended at different times in the past year to "cool down". One has gotten a year-long suspension, one seems to have gotten a year long suspension as well, and the third one's suspension times out in two days. I would be very surprised to see three (at most; post says "many") different high-rep users turn so rude to warrant suspension in the past year, and then claim to be leaving for that very reason.

Comment: There aren't *that* many high-rep suspended users on Physics.SE. [The 3 named in this post are the only ones with over 1k.](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/111211/possibly-suspended-users-with-the-most-rep)

Comment: @Mysticial I said *many*, because there are not lots of experts and high-rep users active on Phys.SE (say, as in Stackoverflow). **Also, the point is that many have become inactive after the suspension of some pivotal users.**

Comment: By pivotal you mean polarizing

Comment: @random anyway, **no one can refuse to accept the crisis in Physics.SE.** I am here asking for help, because there **is** a real issue which has remained unsolved and is ruining the site.

Comment: A a noble prize winner .. awesome

Comment: Thanks for your concerns and trying to help Physics SE, but as you can see no help can be found here. A good idea would be to look at what MathOverflow, which is a rather academic research-level science site, manages to retain its experts, keep up the quality of their content, and adjust the style of moderation on Physics SE accordingly. And please dont mind the downvotes, there is absolutely nothing wrong with your question. It is a well meaned and honest try to help wich is good. The people who are not interested in the issue or do not want to spend time reading it could just ignore it.

Comment: @Dilaton The reason people are probably downvoting is probably shog9's answer. Prior to that one, the votes were going solidly upwards. It is _not_ people being uninterested.

Comment: Ironically, none of the suspended users is a professional physicist.

Comment: A someone who downvoted this prior to Shog's comment, I did so because it seems like this question was posted anonymously to meta for questionable motives which are far more likely to make the situation worse, not better. The fact that it's posted anonymously makes me think that the person knows it was a poor idea, knew so before hand, and just didn't want to take responsibility for it.

Comment: @Sklivvz You know **NOTHING** about the situation, but just know that the *professional* physicists just left themselves after being in that atmosphere.

Comment: @Sklivvz you know absolutely nothing about me, who I am or what I am doing in the "real world", Dimension10 is too young to be an academic (he is only 14 years old, which is easily confirmed when you listen to him explaining physics equations in his Youtube videos), and Ron has a degree in physics and was offerd a PhD position about a topic which he proved himself wrong by mathematical and theoretical considerations (something related to extra-dimensional model building, which is by now disproved experimentally too). So please to not make unfounded assumptions about people you dont know ;-).

Comment: @Dilaton, I'm a bit confused. Skliwz said they are not professional physicists. Your argument is that they are not only not professional physicists, but they also aren't academic physicists either?

Comment: @jmac academic physicists are exclusively professional physicists, but some professional physicists find occupation in other branches too, such as industry, finances, or other things. Yes, Dimension10 is too young, and Ron having a degree in physics means that he has studied (theoretical) physics but not (yet, I am sure he still could if he wanted to) written a PhD thesis. But he had personal conversations with many well known physicists, who obviously liked discussing physics with him because he is so bright. Many real PhD students have less good connections than Ron ...

Comment: One of the suspended users is actually a good physicist, and we (the moderators) tried many ways and many times to get him to conform to the (quite modest) guidelines for civilized conflict on the site (because physics often engenders some conflict). I personally once spent more than an hour painstakingly editing a 30 post comment-string to strip out the personal attacks and leave the interesting and valuable physics argument therein. The user then returned and re-posted the insults and added a few directed at me.

Comment: @VanishedUser I have almost 6000 reputation on Physics. As a comparison, Dilaton and Dimension10 do not reach 4000 (IIRC). Yet in your comments they are "key users" and "I know NOTHING"?

Comment: @Sklivvz Rep is not a good measure of knowledge, you can easily get it from answering easy (homework) and popular questions. There are indeed quite a few users who got above 3000rep by this method (which is quite worysome), whereas some immensely bright theoretical physics students, who give a damn about rep and are only concerned about getting answers to the very nice questions they used to ask, have 1000 < rep < 2000 even though they would make from a physics POV much better informed judgments in the higher order review queues etc ...

Comment: You two need to break it up. Dilaton, Skliwz is not claiming omniscience but rejecting your claim of their ignorance. There is no argument to be had here.

Comment: @Sklivvz Definitely yes. Crazybuddy has 6k reputation and is a first-year undergrad aeronautics student. Also, see Manishearth, who has 11k and is a undergrad engineering student too. Do you consider them *advanced* contributors?

Comment: @VanishedUser I hope you do realise voting is a **community** activity and reputation is entirely **community** generated. Nobody from *outside* the community can do anything about how your community votes *internally*. Its entirely up to you guys to develop standards that in some way promotes PhDs over Bachelors' degrees.

Comment: @VanishedUser CB and I are engineering students. So? We're only engineering students by degree. CB is studying astrophysics on the side. My college's engineering physics branch is ... basically physics. And I intend to continue doing physics after I graduate; I already am doing physics summer projects and whatnot. Yes, I'm an undergrad, much less knowledgeable, and not an advanced contributor. But being an engineering physics student has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS I am trying to be as polite as I possibly can now. You have a fixed view point which you are unwilling to concede. I think it would be best if you maybe started participating on other forums/sites since the only thing I see you doing here (and *I have seen many times in the past*, which is something, as I dont even actively participate on Physics.SE) is acting highly unprofessionally and then complaining about dropping standards.

Comment: He's saying, if you don't like it here you should leave, @DImension. Which is... pretty good advice. It's a big Internet; why do something that makes you unhappy?

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Also, before you consider me condescending let me tell you that the reason I suggested leaving is simply because I have been in a similar situation previously (it was a lot more polite and more private) and things didnt turn out the way I wanted them to. I did push the issue, and eventually had a conversation with Shog and that was it. I didnt like the resolution, but then I realised that its possible that I may be wrong or that I may be *too biased* to look at the situation from a reasonable *unpolarized* perspective. So, I dropped it and took a break from that site.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Clearly, you haven't acted upon your decision... In case you were wondering, you'll find more info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: Dear mods, I did **not** want to start a useless discussion, as we've had many on meta.Physics. I wanted to **inform** you of the bad situation on Phys.SE, and to tell you **seriously** that **whatever the main cause maybe**, the community there is decaying. 
Those professional users (such as Ron) **are** active on other forums themselves; no need to remind them. I'm saying, we, all of us, love to have a good, research-level Q&A site (preferably here for technical reasons, etc.), and ....(next comment)

Comment: **I request your special/immediate attention to prevent the collapse of the site by any means,** if you want to have it active on your network. If you don't act, **all of us will be losers**.
We've tried all we could so far, with no consequence.
That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: Read my answer, @Vanish - then read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124915) and [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4748). I can't "save" P.SE - heck, I'm not even convinced it needs saving. But if it needs anything, it needs the folks who make up the community there to sit down and talk to each other, calmly, *respectfully*, and work out the problems with the site among each other. I'm sick to death of every discussion I see on that site, no matter how trivial, being clogged with juvenile drama... So, will you be part of a solution, or part of the problem?

Comment: Does anybody have the chart of this post score vs. time? I think it would be an interesting read...

Comment: @JanDvorak See Vanished User's expanded reputation log for this question [on their page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/238354/vanished-user?tab=reputation).

Comment: @VanishedUser: I think you missed a point (intentionally??). In my profile, there's a strikeout mentioning that I'm currently learning **Physics** and if you've noticed my messages in h-bar (where I will be, most of the time), you would've known that I hate my engineering course *terribly*. And, as [Manish said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/649366), an engineering degree doesn't explain our interest (nor our knowledge) in Physics. Just like the "rep. score" which is a rough measure of our contribution to SE, the degree is a rough measure of our contribution to engineering ;-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy Haha. *the degree is a rough measure of our contribution to engineering* Well put!

Comment: @AsheeshR: Well, that's true *more or less*. My course doesn't have any Physics at all (other than just formulas to calculate numbers in solids, fluids & crudely approximate them) which explains why my contribution is less (and also, why my degree is at the brink of *extinction*) :P

Comment: @Shog9 Everybody tried it first before they contacted the higher powers, I am sure also in 2013 and also now, 4 years later. 1) In my opinion, you should be able to differentiate an unmoderated site from an overmoderated one. 2) You should check the questions closed as "homework" while they clearly aren't. It doesn't require a physics Phd to differentiate them. 3) Typically the overmodder won't even understand the problem.

Comment: @Shog9 4) I only suggest to compare the core community of the MathSE to the PSE, compare the typical attitude of the site to the new users, and ask, what is the difference. Here lies the answer to the difference between the stats of the sites. | Continuous destructivity, content destruction, user expelling is the common behavior of the core community there, and not the expelled (or, often caged) users did it. All of the expelled people I knew there were friendly and cooperative people there, while the overmoderators exactly opposite.

Comment: I find it amusing that you picked an old complaint about the proliferation of homework on PSE to lament the closing of homework on PSE, @peterh. My answer remains what it was 3 years ago: this is a problem y'all have to solve together. You can't force people to accept - or reject - questions if they want to do otherwise.

Comment: @Shog9 Now, the site has shown its wonderful "pedagogy" by simply banning a young child for "low quality posts", while he produced a lot of good content as well, and the system could hande his bad posts on the usual ways. The same situation on the MathSE hadn't even reached the level of the meta site, his bad posts had benn downvoted/closed/deleted, his good ones had been upvoted, he had got the answers to his questions and you probably hadn't ever heard the he exists. Because the community on the MathSE is friendly, bound by the love of the Math. While the PSE is based on networking.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I think I understand that also your possibilities are limited. I think, a division of the PSE to a professional site (like Mathoverflow) and to an enthusiast one (like MathSE) would solve the problem. I suggest the professional site should get a new name, because the PSE name probably doesn't sound very well in professional circles. | Another idea: if a contact network governs a site, yes they do this very stable and organized, but this site won't be a nice place for newcomers. I think a community should be bound by the love of the site topic and not by a nepotist mentality.

Comment: The person you're probably talking about here has asked *60 times* the number of questions on Physics as they have on Math, and yet even with only three questions has managed to hit a temporary ban at least once on Math, @peterh. There have been considerably more temporary bans and warnings on Physics, to no avail. [There is a proposal for a site where these questions might be more welcome](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102571/speculative-natural-science), if you wish to support it.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, but it was always a temporary, automatic ban and never a mod-provided one. | Any similar initiative would be closed on the Area51 as "PhysicsSE clone", there were numerous tries already and the result was always a ban in the definition phase. Also myself started one or two times, and toke part in others initiatives many times, all of them were closed, mainly as pse clones. I am surprised that this initiative lives even now. Maybe there is some shift in the policies?

Comment: The critical factor, @peterh, is that a new site has to have a topic and audience that aren't currently being served. We're not going to set out to build a "crap questions site", but if you can identify good questions in an area that won't be accepted by current sites, that's an opportunity. Also, all bans are temporary.

Comment: @Shog9 No, a yearlong ban for a 14yr old boy is essentially forever. The automatic suspensions are much shorter. | Check the deleted area51 "pse clones", you have access to them and I can remember. They were closed not in the lack of audience, but they were closed as different reasons (mainly as pse clones). At the time as I toke part in such initiatives, it was clear to me that you have some policy that we can't start a new se site even from the topic who are regularly closed on the pse.

Comment: @Shog9 If you want wellgoing sites with growing stats, try to avoid the frozen, feudal-like vassal hierarchies. They are absolutely not interested in making growing stats, they are interested to cement everything which results unavoidably cemented site stats. This is the reason of the "we are not a homework-solving service" histery. On the MathSE, somehow nobody asks if a question is homework, until it is interesting. They simply don't want the site to grow. Yes, I understand that you can better communicate with stabilized "governing teams" but it is not a job for them as for you.

Comment: A year-long ban at 14 seems long because it represents such a large portion of the life lived thus far, @peterh... But let's not trivialize this; I've helped folks work out of bans during what was actually the *last year of their life* - one would hope that is not the case here. A year is an escalation from numerous shorter bans, and certainly not a first-resort approach. Also, I feel that you're ignoring a rather long and tumultuous history on Math, full of strong arguments and bitter rivals; this trivializes the work they've put in, and sets up bad expectations for Physics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1080/discussion-between-shog9-and-peterh).

Answer (score 138, accepted):

> I want to know if the main moderation team at StackExchange (someone other than the current involved moderators at Phys.SE) can intervene and solve the issues. We really need help.

Be careful what you ask for... The last time we had to step in and help moderate Physics.SE (as in, daily flag-handling, support, etc.) we ended up having to suspend one of the folks on your list because he wouldn't stop harassing people on the site.

You want to know what the problem with Physics.SE is? Most of you don't want to be involved in the dirty, boring parts of running a site, but you'll cheerfully spend all damn day criticizing anyone who is willing to step up and do it.

Tired of lazy homework questions? Then close them. Tired of crackpots arguing endlessly? Down-vote them, and create some guidelines that let you delete such posts / conversations in good conscience. Tired of intelligent, knowledgeable folk leaving? Stop kissing the feet of every loud-mouth who wants a soapbox.

If you don't have the time, guts or talent to do any of that, maybe stop spitting in the faces of the folks who do. Spend some time talking to the moderators, letting them know what you hope to accomplish, and then *get out of their way and let them help you.*

What's that? You say you're unhappy with the moderators *you* elected, and you want folks like me to step in and save you from them? Nonsense - you just want someone else to take your side in yet another stupid, unproductive argument that has nothing to do with Physics and everything to do with your own boredom.

If you want our help, show us that you deserve it - step up and try to do something yourself, using the tools you've been given, and when you hit a roadblock *then* ask for assistance.

Until then, stop whining - you're annoying the folks who are actually trying to get stuff done.

Comment: Rowr!!! If they're bored now what will they be like once they've cracked the secrets of the universe?!!

Comment: @slugster best case: all excited to explain them to everyone in said universe, including to crackpots.

Comment: As I said in my question: ...stupid, unproductive argument... . What do you say about Ben Crowell who left recently?

Comment: @Vanished well, what *should* he say? That it's great? That it's a tragedy? What difference would it make what Shog says about it? His point is that it's up to the Physics community to formulate its own policies that help make the site attractive again. For example, banning homework questions, one of Ben Crowell's main complaints. This (tightening the scope to explicitly exclude non-professionals) has been done before, e.g. on [Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity)

Comment: Hmm, this seems too much like someone who actually knows what's going on. Such bias

Comment: The problem is not the huge number of homework-like questions, but rather the few number (if any) of expert questions. And you definitely know that those suspensions and moderation style caused some very knowledgeable, pivotal experts to become inactive and that was the starting point of the collapse. **You can not/should not behave with nobel prize winners like school kids!!!! But you do. (like deleting their comments and discussions.)** This is what you don't understand.

Comment: The *start*? Oh, good lord no, @Vanished. You think experts weren't leaving until then? Why do you think we were there helping out in the first place?! Were you even around when the discussions you refer to were deleted, when this was all discussed on meta and a compromise arrived at? Did you help in any way, or did you just wring your hands uselessly then too?

Comment: These are communities, websites, not *prisons*, @Vanished. Folks leave. Sometimes, they come back. Would you stand in their way? Tell them, "I say where you go and what you do!"? Surely not. Yet you wonder why someone with many accomplishments would not spend his time where you want him to be for your amusement - this is foolishness! If you want the site to be more welcoming to the folks you respect, then start by doing respectable things on it. Strive to make it a place you're proud of, and then hope that others will be too. This is how good things are born, not from crying and wishing.

Comment: You woke the Shog!  :)

Comment: I'm liking this side of you (but I'm also a little scared of it).

Comment: @VanishedUser you are exactly correct, grown up academics can simply not be bossed around like kindergarten kids by people who know much less about the topic of the site than them. So I expect many more to leave, as the incoming new interesting higher-level questions or new answers to good old questions are declining since for too long now, too. This is why some people are trying to start a new physics site, you can ping me at [TRF](http://motls.blogspot.de/) if you want to know more about it.

Comment: @Shog9 I hope you success with pets.SE, boardgames.SE,...., but forget about Physics.SE .

Comment: The future of Physics is in the hands of its membership, @Vanished. But I appreciate the well-wishes for Pets - I think it's off to a pretty good start.

Comment: @VanishedUser The only argument that you seem to be making here is that anything and everything the "knowledgable" users say should be  preserved and set in stone, while anything and everything that the mods have been telling and doing by spending hours on maintaining the site and doing janitorial work is bull. Please have a look at what Stack Exchange sites are about. Its about communities and groups sharing knowledge, not the personal playground of a few users. Also, had mods been breaking SE policies or violating network standards, they would have been spoken to, before things aggravated.

Comment: @Shog9 Just to remind: He's asked for intervention from moderators  *other than* the currently involved ones!!

Comment: @Mostafa Considering how long this has been going on, its unlikely that anybody from the SE Community team would be unaware of the situation.

Comment: Strictly-speaking, I'm not a moderator @Mostafa - and I'm rarely involved with graduated sites unless someone asks me to be. On a related note, if you have anything you'd like to let us know about your relationship to the OP *before* I get asked to look into that, you might want to do it now.

Comment: We just hired a new gal, @AsheeshR - I guess we could put her on it. But I kinda want her to not quit.

Comment: @Mostafa And when this is provided, he will still ask for intervention from moderators other than the currently involved ones. The grass is always greener in the farther pasture.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm not at all offended by expletives, but I am concerned your use of a mild one will be used as a precedent by others to violate the [SE-wide](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) ban. Please consider replacing it with "nonsense". (I dare not edit a +51-voted answer with such trivialities.)

Comment: @Oddthinking While I feel similar about the precedent thing, note that in general meta sites are much more OK about expletives, though personal attacks are still a big no-no.

Comment: @Oddthinking, the beauty thing about collaborative editing is that if he wants it changed back, he can always do so! (I've made the change so you don't have to, but I don't see any reason to be timid about edits, what's the worst that could happ

Comment: @jmac: I could get shouted at by the big meanies, and made to cry? Yeah, you're right. I should have been **bolder**. Thanks. [ftfy, yw --sklivvz]

Comment: @Shog9 As a somewhat high-rep user of -- and, more importantly, active contributor to -- Physics StackExchange, **thank you**. Every point is spot-on.

Comment: As a relative newbie to Physics.SE, I agree with Chris White

Comment: I agree that the *main* problem is the community, and to a large extent I agree with your answer. But as I said, when Ben Crowell (and some others) left the site (recently, in addition to those who left before), **I just wanted to find a way out of this situation**, and **I didn't want to insult anyone at all.**

Comment: the only way out is what @shog is suggesting. we can't fix your community from the outside. we have a set of rules because, empirically, communities will degenerate if they don't tackle some specific problems. the problems you have are mostly due to having tolerated nasty people because of their technical contributions. the facts are that good contents are ultimately a product of a healthy community and not vice versa

Comment: @Sklivvz I want to assure you that *the current set of rules* can not serve for a High-level physics community, and it will fail, sooner or later. (This is valid about MathOverflow, too. But it's started/grown up out of this atmosphere)
If you want a research-level physics website in your beloved collection, you should seriously think about it.

Comment: @VanishedUser: MathOverflow has succeeded in no small part because they crush relentlessly the kind of behavior that has caused such strife on Physics.  The moderation you've had to endure on Physics is kindergarten stuff compared to the level of oversight the overlords on MathOverflow provide.

Comment: Heh... Just to confirm what @Robert said: the MO mods are awesome people who dearly love their community and are fiercely protective of it. Since upgrading MO to the SE 2.0 platform, I've had the opportunity to more closely *observe* how they handle cranks and malcontents on their site... The Physics mods are *kittens* by comparison.

Comment: @VanishedUser I've seen MO being brought up a lot in the context of these discussions. You know about those civility rules? [They have them, and don't see why an academic community would need the ability to be rude](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1512/what-is-your-stance-on-civility/).

Comment: @Manishearth on MO (and on TP it was the same) as correctly said, the moderators nicely defend the interests and needs of the **contributing** community, keep up the level of the site, and see to it that a nice academic collegial atmosphere can be maintained. This is exactly as it should be...

Comment: You do know that "needs of the community" is a nebulous concept, right? The community is a bunch of people. Not all may agree on the needs. And I think that that hread is evidence enough that the m oderarors and the community would not shirk from chastising a good contributor for civility breaches (It is possible that this has already happen ed, I don't know). Do you have any evidence to the contrary? If so, let's hear it. It shouldn't be hard t I find; if  such behavior is tolerated then you should find comments of the same type.

Comment: @Manishearth I think it is not important what exactly the needs of the community are, as long as the moderators take its opinion serious and act accordingly this is good. And from what I observe on MO, they do this nicely. Sure, I can investigate their meta to see, if there are outbursts of strong disagreement too, they surely tolerate not everything. But fact is that I at least would not have to disagree there in the first place (for others I can not speak), and in the election the candidates seem to have been all good mathematical researchers themself, respected by and appreciated by all.

Comment: Nice U-turn, @Dilaton. I feel the same way, we should respect the opinion of community members and take it seriously. Whether or not we act on it is a different matter, like I said, not everyone may agree on that. But we do take it into account.  And I'm appalled that you think we don't take the opinion seriously -- we have patiently listened to the _same_ unsubstantiated opinions _over and over again_ on meta. We've listened to people claiming that any and every policy they disagree with was tantamount to suppressing the high level community here or some such.

Comment: We've patiently addressed all the points that were repeatedly brought up on meta, getting into the same arguments over and over again. The (substantiated) points we made were ignored; and nobody brought up further substantiation. We've even listened to sweeping claims that the opinion of some users is the opinion of the whole site, and that a specific portion of physics should be given more importance than others. All these opinions, we listened to, and we patiently replied. Again. And again. We took them into account, too, and some were acted upon.

Comment: Complaints against non mainstream physics ("crackpots") led to the formulation of the related policy. After listening to the book policy debate I sat down and read all the posts I could find about it on meta and the blog, and then had some discussions. I spent time identifying the issues and coming up with ways around them. This led to the new book policy. Yes, it hasn't been implemented yet, but that's just because very few people have been willing to step up and help with it. So what if we didn't act on the opinions about suspensions?

Comment: There were opinions on the other side of the fence too, and just because we disagree with you doesn't mean we don't respect your opinion. While this was off-site, I've seen you call all the users who disagree with you as trolls; so I really don't think _you_, of all people, are in any position to say that the moderators of Physics.SE don't take the opinions of other members seriously.

Comment: Oh, and also, [Math Overflow doesn't allow long comment discussions either and suspends for it](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1066/protest-for-my-account-suspension), and this seems to be a [pretty old policy](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/91/comment-threads-that-become-discussions/#Item_0). Also, see the last comment [here](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/317/perception-of-moderators-by-mo-users/).

Comment: @Manishearth I have not looked into what was the issue between this user and MathOverflow ... But they seem to rather preserve content (including comments) as you can see [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1122/30967). With the book policy I would still be willing to help because I promised and I think it is important. But as you probably know I rather doubt, that it will be implemented in finite time. I did not understand what is missing in Nathaniels suggestion concerning the questions with potentially several legitimate answers (list), why it was not implemented as he has formulated it.

Comment: Maybe others were unsure about that too, which prevented them from formulating something? Yes, on another site I sometimes have to steem off (without thinking), but I would be more happy if things had not gone that far, and could have been reasonably resolved instead ...

Comment: @Dilaton If you notice the other post, they used to copy long discussions to the old meta. Just like we do here, we copy to chat. As for Nathaniel's list questions proposal, I mentioned that wording changes go pretty far in making these work -- "appropriately restrictive" lists are usually non-lists in spirit. (let's not continue this discussion here, it's tangential. Thanks for reminding me though, I will remember to have another look at the post and see if I can finish my answer later, though this may take a while. Or maybe I'll bring it up as part of the other recent meta posts)

Comment: Re:finite: Well, if the community isn't stepping up, are they really interested in it? Personally I'd like to see it implemented, but it's not a task the mod team can do alone as we have many other things taking up our time. Re:Reasonably resolved: That's the thing, you consider anything that didn't go as you wanted it to initially as not reasonably resolved. Maybe if you didn't view us as people who don't want Physics.SE to succeed, you would get somewhere on that front.

Comment: I think Shog would appreciate it (as would I) if this discussion ended here. We're going waaay off topic, I just wanted to point out that the mods have been taking opinion pretty seriously. (Apologies, @Shog, for derailing the thread)

Comment: Shog9 how can it be that some people are allowed to post [such](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12012933#12012933) offensive comments in chat? The OP of this comment blatantly (and intentionally?) misrepresents the physics knowledge of the user he attacks so it is wrong, and second this comment name-calling comment is very insulting. I thought things like such blatant name-calling for example is not allowed on SE. Why does this comment not get deleted?

Comment: Did you *flag it*, @Dilaton? I'm fairly certain that comment references a person on a different website, but if you have concerns about it then raise them via the usual avenues.

Comment: @Shog9 from the context I am quite sure that the comment is about Dimesion10 as his comments are the topic of the surrounding discussion... I am currently not able to talk or flag in any chatroom, otherwise I would have done it. And I am not able to post on the appropriate meta of the site either, so it seems I can not make use of the usual avenues (or is there an option I am missing?) ...

Comment: Sounds like you've really made things difficult for yourself then, @Dilaton. But yes, there are other avenues. Since this is completely off-topic, I'm going to suggest you contact us via either the link at the bottom of the page or [chat].

Comment: The question closing policy is pathologic on the PSE, this is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 57):

As you posted with a sock puppet I'll address the vocal dissenters ( Dimension/Dilaton/...) directly.

Ron's suspension was perfectly valid, he habitually ignores the rules and has announced a few times on different sites that he'll never follow them. I was watching most of the stuff that happened when he was suspended, and he was just throwing a temper tantrum because one of the moderator candidates was someone he didn't like.

As for everything that has happened after that, I haven't seen such destructive and immature behaviour on any SE site so far. You're always assuming the worst about the moderator's motives when they act, you never even consider that they could have well-intentioned reasons to act that way. You imply or outright accused the mods of deleting posts just because they disagree with them and to suspend users just because they don't like them. You spend hours upon hours to insult Physics.SE users on your comment page on Lubos' blog, calling them "obnoxious non-physics trolls", "politically trolling shithead", "totalitarian monarchs" and similar insults. Anyone that disagrees with you is assumed a non-physicist that only wants to suppress you for political reasons.

You're not helping Physics.SE, you're trying to divide it and destroy it if you don't get your way.

Comment: Yes, this happened to me, merely because I liked how another member's profile was written (and stated that I did not care who it was about, just it was written well in my view).  On that blog, my character was dissected by people who do not know me at all.  Regardless of what they assume, I am a physicist and I am happy with my life.  They're opinions of me are just words on a blog by names on the screen.

Answer (score 40):

As an observer from the inside, here's my view. I've shared this about a million times between the Physics meta and the Physics chat, so what's one more time.

### Homework

Do homework questions suck? Sure they do, they're annoying, particularly when they show absolutely zero research effort, are poorly formed, and come in with a "you owe me the answer to this immediately" attitude. But rather than whine and moan, I do my part (because, ya know, I'm part of the community) to clean them up. I downvote, I edit, I flag, and then *I move on with my life*. There's a reason I've cast hundreds of flags. Do I wish there were more technical questions in my field? Absolutely I do. That's why I am still 25 rep away from 3k. And once I get there, you better believe I'll be closing down really bad questions every chance I get.

Most of my time on SE is really spent doing the janitorial work with the tools I have available to me. I'm busy trying to get my research done and don't have time to answer questions but I do have time to take 5 minutes every few hours and make sure that other people can; that the good questions aren't lost forever in the abyss of homework. Why? Because I see the potential of the site rather than lament the demise. I'd rather take 5 minutes to be part of the solution than complain about the symptoms.

### Atmosphere

One of the underlying issues is the suspension of high-rep users who make supposedly significant contributions to the site. This cause other high-rep users to leave. Okay, so we've lost let's say 5-6 users (not all of them significant contributors, but let's just stick with that number) that you can count due to that.

Do you know how many "well respected" potential users were turned off from the site because of the belligerent nature of suspended users? Neither do I. But maybe 10 Nobel laureates took one look at it and said "I don't want to take time to help somebody and be insulted doing it" and walked away.

More to the point, how many good users have been turned away by the acrimonious environment created by this insistence that nobody takes the site seriously and that it's a massive conspiracy to do away with "serious physics?" Do you know? I don't. But I have never in my life heard somebody say "Hey, the people over there are really intelligent and friendly. I think I'll avoid them."

So users who are leaving because the signal to noise ratio is too low, I honestly don't blame them. Because what other reason is there to stay when the environment is so toxic? And, I hate to burst the bubbles of the minority here, but the toxic environment is not created by the moderators. Despite your accusations.

Lastly, Johnathan Hobbs pointed this out in a comment on another answer and I've said it repeatedly too but the message bears repeating. **The way in which you present yourself instantly turns people away**. Nobody likes a bunch of people who do nothing but insult others and whine. It's not even the message but how it's conveyed. And this is what lead to the suspensions to begin with -- just because you disagree with somebody doesn't mean you have to be rude when you tell them! There is a **HUGE** difference between "This answer is incorrect because you forgot to consider factor X" and "This is flat out wrong. Downvote! It's stupid that you didn't think about X."

Your supporters say that you have to be argumentative in physics. I disagree. You have to be willing to debate, but not argue. I have never gotten a paper review back that says "You're just a crackpot, REJECT!" because that's insane anybody would do that. And yet that's what the comments tend to be on questions or answers.

### Conclusion

Here's the thing. You contend:

> Now, many of the users there believe that the arguably authoritarian, thoughtless and naive style of moderation is the main cause of these issues.

I contend that the disgusting and irritating environment created by a select few users who insist that the moderators are only out to censor and suppress them, and that the user base is out to destroy the study of physics are the main cause of much deeper issues. Why on Earth would **anybody** who reads the posts of the very vocal minority want to jump right in and participate? Why would anybody from the outside look at it and say "Hey, here's a group I can get behind?" Why would good users who see a lull in questions they like to answer decide to stick around just to hear more of the same old whining? Who is to say that you're not causing more problems than you would be solving?

You don't like it? Then get the heck out. Good riddance.

Comment: You now have 3k rep on physics. Use your new powers wisely, young padawan.

Comment: Well said, @tpg2114, especially about the papers - I have had 4 lots of feedback back lately and the errors, misunderstandings (on both sides) were communicated politely - the notion that being impolite is necessary to Physics is just an opinion of a few - the physicists I work with (internationally in real life) are all polite.

Comment: Most of the questions closed on the PSE as "homework", clearly visible aren't.

Answer (score 26):

First, I'm sure that the Community Managers are aware of the situation(s) on Physics, and they are probably considering what should be done.

Also, if you want to talk to 'the people in charge', there is a **contact us** link at the bottom of every page:

[image]

Or email `team@stackexchange.com`. Messages sent via either means are considered confidential and aren't shared with anyone outside of the SE team.

Comment: Both means go to the same place. The contact form is generally more reliable because Google sometimes likes to trap real emails sent directly to team@ in the spam folder where we will never see them because of the sheer amounts of actual spam we get. (And also because hardly anyone opens the actual mailbox since we switched to Zendesk.)

Answer (score 17):

I'll note that the Nobel prize winner vanished after being repeatedly harangued by one of those suspended users. So maybe, just maybe, those suspensions aren't part of the problem: maybe they are part of the solution.

I notice that one of the other suspended users, DImension10, has deleted their answer from here. And then, after it was restored by one mod, it was deleted again by the community and a mod (thanks for the correction Sklivvz)

I think that's a shame, because the answer illustrated some of the problems we have over on Physics.SE.

Though not in the way the author intended.

Because DImension10's answer illustrated the problem that Physics.SE has, I've reproduced it below, because it answers the OP's question, though not in the way that DImension10 intended. **It answers it by demonstrating by example what is wrong on Physics.SE.**

Readers here who have not kept up with the meta.physics of this, may wish to know that some physics users named in the question above are trying to set up a competitor site to Physics.SE outside the Stack Exchange. So their behaviour in dragging Physics.SE down (and trying to [get it closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203225/164022)) is consistent with trying to boost their own putative competitor site. Ironically, they even use Stack Exchange chat, profiles and meta questions to try to promote their (as yet non-existent) competitor site.

Anyway, here's the deleted answer, which stood at +2/-31 when I grabbed it. I've made one edit; in an edit, Shog replaced a swear word in their answer with the word "nonsense"; so I've made the same edit to the quoted text below.

Don't shoot me, I'm only the messenger.

---

Answered 2013-10-31 04:32:47Z [DImension10 Abhimanyu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/228266/dimension10-abhimanyu-ps)

> If I have permission to, let me point out how fundamentally stupid
>   Shog9's answer is.
>
> > Be careful what you ask for... The last time we had to step in and help moderate Physics.SE (as in, daily flag-handling, support, etc.)
> >     we ended up having to suspend one of the folks on your list because he
> >     wouldn't stop harassing people on the site.
>
> *Harassing people?* Criticisting wrong answers is *harassing them?* You've obviously not seen any real physics, which is why you think
>   that criticism is harassment. Who criticise in programming? It's
>   impossible to convince **you**, but let me at least try to convince
>   someone else who is hopefully open-minded enough to listen for a
>   while.
>
> **Physics does not run on stupid opinions, what the stupid media says is right, or what armchair people say is right.** It is obvious that
>   you will have arguments of **facts** in Physics, because it's not
>   programming, where you can only say "Hey, I like this language!", "No
>   I like this language", "NO, THAT!", etc. Therefore, you think that
>   physics is the same.
>
> In my opinion, it's you who is being the "harass"ing person, as you
>   don't even have facts to support your argument.
>
> > You want to know what the problem with Physics.SE is? Most of you
> >     don't want to be involved in the dirty, boring parts of running a
> >     site, but you'll cheerfully spend all damn day criticizing anyone who
> >     is willing to step up and do it.
>
> Like *whom*? Who, precisely, is this wonderful person? Is it you,
>   Shog9?
>
> Contrary to your claims, we are criticising people who don't give a
>   crap about the site, and only want to earn lots of money from the
>   site.
>
> That's *you*, Stack Overflow.
>
> > Tired of lazy homework questions? Then close them.    Ok, here, you have finally made a sensible point. Indeed, there are very few \geq
> >     3000 users who are actually voting to close/reopen. See
> >     [How much are 3k+ users moderating through the review queue?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/how-much-are-3k-users-moderating-through-the-review-queue).
>
> But the problem is, that while mods say that they have refrained from
>   the close vote queue, this is only for the bad questions! They
>   continue to close the good questions as primarily this, too that.
>   What's the problem if a question is slightly opinion-based?
>
> What's the problem with book questions? What's the problem with career
>   advice?
>
> > Tired of crackpots arguing endlessly? Down-vote them, and create some guidelines that let you delete such posts / conversations in good
> >     conscience.
>
> Who creates the guidelines? The moderators/. There is a non-mainstream
>   policy, but it is often not used, with pathetic excuses, and it
>   doesn't even apply to answers!
>
> Crackpot answers are "just wrong"!.
>
> > Tired of intelligent, knowledgeable folk leaving? Stop kissing the
> >     feet of every loud-mouth who wants a soapbox.
>
> Tell that to your disciples.
>
> > If you don't have the time, guts or talent to do any of that, maybe
> >     stop spitting in the faces of the folks who do.
>
> Again, who is this saint? You?
>
> > Spend some time talking to the moderators, letting them know what you
> >     hope to accomplish, and then *get out of their way and let them help
> >     you.*
>
> Like they care, anyway.
>
> > What's that? You say you're unhappy with the moderators *you* elected, and you want folks like me to step in and save you from them?
>
> What do you expect us to do if the moderators turn into people who
>   don't care about the community, and only about the "SE Model", shun
>   the 2 only good moderators (mbq and Qmechanic, who actually care about
>   the community), etc.?
>
> And *we did not* elect all of them. The harm-meaning folks from the
>   other sites who never actually care about the site have proven to
>   suddenly start caring about the elections, as can be seen about last
>   year's elections, from the now-censored post who'se html can be found
>   over here: http://psiepsilon.wikia.com/wiki/Ron_Maimon_Suspension.
>
> And don't worry, no matter how much you've censored, the WayBack
>   Machine is there to help us. It now even allows us to archive webpages
>   our selves, from the "`/record`" page. I have archived everything and
>   have them here:
>   http://psiepsilon.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Dimension10/Future_Plans_for_this_Wiki#Physics_Stack_Exchange.
>
> > Nonsense - you just want someone else to take your side in yet another
> >     stupid, unproductive argument that has nothing to do with Physics and
> >     everything to do with your own boredom.
>
> Oh, yes, of course. We just get *bored* when Ron Maimon got suspended,
>   isn't it ?.
>
> > If you want our help, show us that you deserve it - step up and try to
> >     do something yourself, using the tools you've been given, and when you
> >     hit a roadblock *then* ask for assistance.
>
> Nobody needs- your help=.
>
> > Until then, stop whining - you're annoying the folks who are actually
> >     trying to get stuff done.
>
> That's you, isn't it?.
>
> So, after writing your answer, did you ban yourself for unfounded
>   accusations/violation of the "Be Nice" Rule?    \          If not, why
>   do these stupid rules only apply to the normal people? Huh?
>
> You obviously want to make another crackpot-filthy wikipedia.
>
> Oh, and I *kindly apologise* for the rudeness in this post, but it's
>   obviously useless to think that "Well, the mods really don't "not
>   care" about Phys.SE, they just,... don't know how to handle it, maybe
>   they're deaf or something.".

---

Like I say, I've just copied & pasted DImenstion10's answer, because I think it exemplifies the challenges that the moderators of Physics.SE face. Don't shoot me, I'm only the messenger.

Comment: Correction: the answer has been nuked by the community and one mod.

Comment: Well, the first time Dim10 nuked it himself (and after accusing the people who had cast two votes to delete it as a non-answer of censorship). To judge by his comment above he did that in order to be able to cast down votes. Then he seems to have wanted it both ways and undeleted it. *Then* it was deleted by a user and a mod.

Comment: The description of the purpose of a new higher-level physics site in this answer is not correct: As the working name of the project PhysicsOverflow says, its relation to Physics SE should be very similar as the relation of MathOverflow to Mathematics SE. The originial site meant to be some kind of a higher-level PhysicsOverflow complementing Physics SE, Theoretical Physics SE, did not attract a large enough community to be maintained inside the SE network. So it is more reasonable to some kind of restart it with with a slightly broadend scope outside the SE network, instead of venturing ...

Comment: ... a restart at Area51 to not having to fullfill externally prescribed growth and activity criteria. And yes, another (in my personal opinion) advantage of doing it outside SE is that the new site will not have to comply with the SE model and the community can determin all policies and rules by itself. Reading recently a few comments of other people fearing that Physics SE will not survive in the long run, together with some recent meta posts, made me worry too. So I asked [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203225/184300) meta question to investigate if graduated sites can get closed too

Comment: for some reason in principle, or if they are save. Happily I learned that such a things are really not expected and most importantly, what I read out of the discussions to this thread, it will not happen to Physics SE ...

Answer (score 11):

Well tl;dr is an understatement for this post. I feel like I read a novel. Shog makes such an excellent point about *community*. Act together as a community to solve problems or it will be difficult to come together on solutions.

In my opinion, the exchange system is not set up purely for professors and professionals to post their findings. As mentioned earlier, it is for professionals *and* enthusiasts. It just so happens that most students are enthusiastic.

I know a lot of professors, and some Nobel prize winners at UCSB (they have several in physics). Those people are **busy**. And by busy, I mean that they are being leaned on by their institution to produce the next Nobel prize - not an easy task. Expecting this caliber of person to be actively contributing is a tall order.

All contributions should be appreciated, and taken for what they are. Thus, if a contribution is of little to no value it is downvoted and its folly highlighted. It is important to attract the future contributors of a community, not just to retain current ones. If that means that some people get help with what they got stuck on, albeit homework in some cases (although not copy paste assignments requesting others to do their entire work - no one likes those), then so be it.

In my opinion, there is not a suppression of professionals as much as an increase in enthusiasts. Enthusiasts are important too. Keep in mind that Fall is usually the most active time for the exchanges from a traffic perspective.

Last I checked Jon Skeet doesn't have a PhD, but his contribution to stackoverflow is priceless.

Comment: The Jon Skeet example doesnt really make sense in the case of Stack Overflow. He was part of the team that designed a programming language (C#). I think thats as high as it goes in the field of professional programming.

Comment: @AsheeshR - Hard to quote every comment I read for perfect context. My point there was in reference to the back and forth about students or professors. The point being that the user does not have to be a professor in order to teach. And although I believe Jon Skeet could probably design the c# language, I am fairly certain he had nothing to do with its inception given that he had only just graduated a year before its appearance and he was not a MS MVP until 2003.

Comment: My bad. My statement was incomplete. He was part of the team that worked on one version of C# and wrote the specs for it or something along those lines.

Comment: @AsheeshR Are you sure you're not thinking of Eric Lippert?  Granted I'm not an expert on Jon's history, but I'm pretty sure he's never worked at Microsoft.