# Vote Count Wrapping Issue on Some Questions in Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

In the Android app, the vote count on some questions gets wrapped. Thanks to Doorknob's comment I've found that it doesn't appear to be on just those with double digit negative vote counts or those with vote counts of 100 or more. As you can see in one of the screenshots below, the question has a vote count of 429 but is not getting wrapped. Another with 121 votes is though. Each question I've come across with double digit negative vote counts does get wrapped (3 examples of those below).

Same result in both horizontal and vertical orientations. Not sure if it's different on a larger screen size though (mine screen size is 4.3).

I'm on version 0.1.58

Here are links and screenshots for examples:

**Negative Vote Counts**

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203860/222390
- [auto-open a question if it has a very high amount of upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203803/222390)
- [Physics is rotting into a bad situation, a request for community manager intervention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203643/222390)

[image]

---

**100+ Vote Counts Wrapped**

- [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/222390)

[image]

---

**100+ Vote Counts Not Wrapped**

- [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/222390)

[image]

Comment: Is it the same for posts with more than 100 votes? (just curious; I don't have the app so I can't test it)

Comment: It does on some with three digits. I'll update the post shortly.

Comment: @TimStone you are correct, I didn't see that post. Thanks and sorry about not seeing it. Should I just delete this one?